# Hibernate configuration on runtime

Tags: java, hibernate

I have hibernate.cfg.xml file.

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url"></property>
    <property name="connection.username"></property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property> 

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
```

.....................

This is the most interesting part of file.
Now i must set missing values: url, username, password.
I'm trying to do in such way:

```
public static void SetSessionFactory() {
    try {

      AnnotationConfiguration conf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();
      // <!-- Database connection settings -->
      conf.setProperty("connection.url", URL);
      conf.setProperty("connection.username", USERNAME);
      conf.setProperty("connection.password", PASSWORD);
      SESSION_FACTORY = conf.buildSessionFactory();

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      // Log exception!
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
  }
```

But it just loads my configuration from hibernate.cfg.xm and do not changing any property...

url, username, passoword - are command-line arguments so i must set them on runtime.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to call `conf.configure();` here.
And properties may need to have hibernate prefix like "hibernate.connection.username"
Hope it helps.

Comment: maaaaaagic ^_^
Added hibernate. to property names in cfg file and in SetSessionFactory method and all works now!

Answer (score 4):

Try like this it is working fine

```
AnnotationConfiguration conf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("/dronehibernate.cfg.xml");

conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:mysql://localhost/PAT_DRONE_DB1");

SessionFactory sessionFactory = conf.buildSessionFactory();

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

List<NetworkType> channelList = session.createQuery("from NetworkType").list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use constants from `Environment` class