# Hibernate - changing connection string during runtime

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jsf

I have JSF + Hibernate app. During runtime, i need to change database, to which user is connected. For example, User can manually switch databases in my app, so app is connected to the chosen one. I read about Hibernate Connection Provider. Can it help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate configuration on runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341871/hibernate-configuration-on-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341871/hibernate-configuration-on-runtime) before.

Comment: This is not a respond, this is a comment.